# A recent change in Tomcat 8 on Amazon Linux has caused a problem with compression

Tags: tomcat

I have a Tomcat webapp (used as an API for REST services) running on Amazon Linux, and it has been up and running for several years. (It's Tomcat 8).

I apply software updates regularly (sudo yum update). After one such update about a month ago, many of my REST services started to fail, or more precisely, the client making the request hung waiting for it to finish.

What's causing this is some change to the way Tomcat compresses responses. In my server.xml file, I have compression="on" in the Connector element (along with a list of compressible mine types, such as application/json).

If I turn compression off, everything works correctly again.

How does Tomcat compress responses? Which algorithms does it use, and can I specify what I want? Is it a change in the Tomcat code itself what would have caused this problem or is it a change in the operating system?

Comment: It might be a Java update that is the cause as well. I believe that Tomcat ultimately uses the java.util.zip classes to do the compression.

Comment: I think the Content-Length header of the compressed response (gzip) is still set to the length of the original uncompressed data. Since the compressed data is smaller, the client hangs waiting for the rest of it. As this is happening on more than one client (Postman as well as iOS and Android apps) it seems to be a server-side problem.